# Access forbidden by rule - Nginx Logging

Tags: nginx, logging

We are keep getting spammed and receive these error messages:

```
[error] 1414#1414: *1327 access forbidden by rule, client: 2a23:4722:3:1::2e, server: ourname.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1", host: "www.ourname.com"
```

These shouldn't be logged as we have defined:

```
location = /xmlrpc.php {deny all;access_log off;log_not_found off;}
```

Why are these messages still logged?

Comment: You could try `return 403;` instead of the `deny all;`, which gives the response, but may eliminate the error message.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Is it possible to just add "error_log off;" to the location rule? Should I just be using a tool to filter out these errors and not be concerned about them in the log? I don't really see the point in them being there, if they're nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All directives such "access_log" and "log_not_found" refer to access_log. But your log is error_log.
I think better use something like that

```
location = /xmlrpc.php {
  return 403;
  access_log off;
}
```

bots will receive "Forbidden"
or

```
location = /xmlrpc.php {
  return 404; 
  access_log off;
}
```

bots will receive "Not Found"

or maybe return 444 (hard way)